# SQL Server: How do I work out what is changing my data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's a simplified version of my problem:

I have lots of articles in a table. Say, 10,000 rows. About once a week 5-10 of the values of the ArticleAuthor column [Nvarchar(255)] get overwritten with the same data - all from another article.

The code is actaully really huge and old and it's proved tough to find the offending process.

I'm thinking I might put a temporary trigger on the table to log when it gets updated etc and work from there.

Anyone got any better ideas?

Thanks in advance!

I'm using SQL Server 2005 by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use SQL Profiler and leave it running for a week and then parse the result log to find the offending process.  Make sure you use filters though to trim down the logging.

Comment: Good idea. I was thinking about this as well, but was concerned about the resource usage on the production DB. I know it would be hard for you to say, but considering we don't normally have resource issues on that DB, do you think SQL Profile warrants a concern?

Comment: if you have an idea of what queries are causing the issue and you limit your profile to just those it shouldn't have all that big of an impact.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark - I'll test this out this week and mark it as an answer if I get the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the data provides you date/time information a temporary trigger is probably the best starting point.  You could also try searching application code for keywords like ('UPDATE TABLENAME' or 'Set ArticleAuthor=').  I would also take a look at the triggers that are already on the table to make sure none of them contain the rogue code.

Comment: Thanks @user. where do you think I should search for this SQL? are you suggesting in the code or the log? If you mean the log, could you please give me details of how to go about it?

Comment: @Ev: The `definition` column of [`sys.sql_modules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) would be the place to look, if you don't have the application code scripted out to files.  A query like (untested) `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id) AS name, m.* FROM sys.sql_modules AS m WHERE definition LIKE '%UPDATE TABLENAME%'` would probably help.

Comment: Ah I get you. Thanks for the help. That's a great way of finding more specific dependancies than the GUI method. Unforuntaely I've already worked from this angle, finding possible stored procs, then finding them in the code - to no avail. I'm thinking more like looking at a log to find the specific offending SQL and what happened around that to maybe track down where the issue came from.